# "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows" vs. "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller"

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I recently bought an "[Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QRKWKQ)". It came with a little USB dongle for my computer to pick up the wireless signal and some driver software. It works like a charm.

I plan to have some multiplayer games on my computer, so I want to hook up three more wireless controllers. Here's my question: should I buy more "Wireless Controllers for Windows", which are a little more expensive than just regular Xbox 360 Wireless Controllers. or now that I have the driver software and the USB dongle, can I just buy regular [Xbox 360 Wireless Controllers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSP0WW)?

Is there any actual difference in the controller hardware itself?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: You changed the title of the question, but what you changed it to is in fact not the focus of the question. The question is whether there was any actual difference between the two controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just buy a normal Xbox 360 controller. The only difference between both of them is that one comes with the dongle. There is no "Windows" and "Xbox" controller they work for both.